# How to calculate the circumferences of two pulley wheels connected by a pulley belt

Tags: geometry

Can we calculate the circumferences of two pulley wheels connected by a pulley belt given only the length of the pulley belt as **X** and the difference in number of revolutions between two wheels given as **Y** considering that pulley belt has done only 1 revolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see.

There are three unknowns: the distance $d$ between the pulleys (centers, or axes), the radius $r$ of the smaller pulley, and the radius $R$ of the larger pulley. The circumferences of the pulleys are of course $2\pi r$ and $2 \pi R$, respectively.

In practice, the pulleys cannot overlap, so $d \gt r + R$, but let's ignore this restriction for now: the OP is not interested in $d$ anyway.

When the belt of length $X$ does one full rotation, each pulley turns the number of rotations matching the ratio of belt length to pulley circumference. If we use $n$ for the turns on the smaller pulley, and $N$ on the larger pulley, then
$$n = \frac{X}{2 \pi r }, \; N = \frac{X}{2 \pi R}$$

If $n = Y + N$, i.e. $Y$ is the number of revolutions the smaller pulley does compared to the larger pulley, when the belt does a full rotation, then we get the equation
$$\frac{X}{2 \pi r} = Y + \frac{X}{2 \pi R}$$
We can solve that for $X$,
$$X = \frac{2 \pi Y R r}{R - r}$$
or for $R$,
$$R = \frac{X r}{X - 2 \pi Y r}$$
or for $r$,
$$r = \frac{X R}{2 \pi Y R + X}$$
but not more than one, as these equations are not linearly independent. This is not enough to solve both $r$ and $R$ at the same time.

Let's examine the expression for the belt length $X$. For simplicity, let's say that we might have a constant $Z$, which tells us the gap between the pulleys, i.e. $$d = r + Z + R$$

The belt leaves both pulleys tangentially (if properly tensioned). That is, the belt covers angle $180° + 2 \varphi$ on the bigger pulley, and $180° - 2 \varphi$ on the smaller pulley, with
$$\varphi = \arctan\left(\frac{R - r}{\sqrt{(Z + 2 R)(Z + 2 r)}}\right)$$
The length of the belt $X$ is
$$X = 2 \sqrt{(Z + 2 R)(Z + 2 r)} + (R + r) \pi + 2 (R - r) \varphi$$
i.e.
$$X = 2 \sqrt{(Z + 2 R)(Z + 2 r)} + (R + r) \pi + 2 (R - r) \arctan\left(\frac{R - r}{\sqrt{(Z + 2 R)(Z + 2 r)}}\right)$$

Unfortunately, due to how nonlinear $\varphi$ is, there are no algebraic solutions for $R$ or $r$ from the above, when $X$ is known (even if $Z$ was also known).

To find a numerical solution, one needs to fix one of $Z$, $R$, or $r$; thus, there are no numerical solutions either, unless $Z$ is fixed.

This yields the short answer of **No, $X$ and $Y$ are not enough to determine the circumferences of the pulleys**.